# How do i find all possible permutations of the first 1-2 letters of each word?

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
inputs <- c("Master", "Bachelor", "School")
```

I would like to have all possible permutations of the first 1-2 letters of each
word.

```
first_letter <- sapply(inputs, substr, start = 1, stop = 1)
"M" "B"  "S"

second_letter <- sapply(inputs, substr, start = 1, stop = 2)
"Ma"     "Ba"     "Sc"
```

**Desired output:**

All permutations of the first letters in every order, see the columns of
variable "all_order" (see section "What i tried").
Also in both variations, so either take the first value of
"first_letter" or first value "second_letter" but not both at the same time.

> MBaS, MBS, MBSc, MBaSc MaBaS, MaBS, MaBSc, MaBaSc,
>
> SBM, SBaM, SBaMa, SBaM ScBM, ScBaM, ScBaMa, ScBaM
>
> BSM, BSMa, BScM, BScMa BaSM, BaSMa, BaScM, BaScMa,
>
> .....

(Let me know if it is explained well enough.)

**What i tried:**

```
combs <- combn(rep(seq(inputs), 2), 3)
keep <- !colSums(apply(combs, 2, duplicated))
all_order <- combs[, keep]

all_order
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    2    2    3    1
[2,]    2    2    3    2    3    1    1    2
[3,]    3    3    2    3    1    3    2    3
```

Comment: What was the result of what you tried? Did it achieve your goal or fall short?

Comment: You're looking for *permutations* of them, not *combinations*, is that right?

Comment: @norie: the all_order variable just gives me all possible orders of the words. But it does not incorporates the requirement that i want to use either the first 1 or 2 letters of each word.

Comment: @r2evans: You are right, permutation, i will correct that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll use `gtools::permutations` to calculate the ... *permutations* of `inputs`, and then use `expand.grid` to show all combinations within them.

First, we can do it easily on one order of the inputs with:

```r
expand.grid(c("M","Ma"), c("B","Ba"), c("S","Sc"))
#   Var1 Var2 Var3
# 1    M    B    S
# 2   Ma    B    S
# 3    M   Ba    S
# 4   Ma   Ba    S
# 5    M    B   Sc
# 6   Ma    B   Sc
# 7    M   Ba   Sc
# 8   Ma   Ba   Sc
do.call(paste, c(expand.grid(c("M","Ma"), c("B","Ba"), c("S","Sc")), sep = ""))
# [1] "MBS"    "MaBS"   "MBaS"   "MaBaS"  "MBSc"   "MaBSc"  "MBaSc"  "MaBaSc"
```

Now that's one order (`M` < `B` < `S`), now we need to rearrange them. We might call all orderings manually, or we can use `gtools::permutations` to help.

```r
inputlist <- lapply(inputs, substring, 1, 1:2)
str(inputlist)
# List of 3
#  $ : chr [1:2] "M" "Ma"
#  $ : chr [1:2] "B" "Ba"
#  $ : chr [1:2] "S" "Sc"

perms <- gtools::permutations(3, 3)
perms
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    2    3
# [2,]    1    3    2
# [3,]    2    1    3
# [4,]    2    3    1
# [5,]    3    1    2
# [6,]    3    2    1
inputlist[perms[2,]]
# [[1]]
# [1] "M"  "Ma"
# [[2]]
# [1] "S"  "Sc"
# [[3]]
# [1] "B"  "Ba"
inputlist[perms[3,]]
# [[1]]
# [1] "B"  "Ba"
# [[2]]
# [1] "M"  "Ma"
# [[3]]
# [1] "S"  "Sc"
```

Resulting in

```r
allperms <- do.call(rbind,
  apply(gtools::permutations(3, 3), 1, 
        function(ind) do.call(expand.grid, inputlist[ind]))
)
head(allperms); tail(allperms)
#   Var1 Var2 Var3
# 1    M    B    S
# 2   Ma    B    S
# 3    M   Ba    S
# 4   Ma   Ba    S
# 5    M    B   Sc
# 6   Ma    B   Sc
#    Var1 Var2 Var3
# 43    S   Ba    M
# 44   Sc   Ba    M
# 45    S    B   Ma
# 46   Sc    B   Ma
# 47    S   Ba   Ma
# 48   Sc   Ba   Ma
do.call(paste, c(allperms, list(sep = "")))
#  [1] "MBS"    "MaBS"   "MBaS"   "MaBaS"  "MBSc"   "MaBSc"  "MBaSc"  "MaBaSc" "MSB"    "MaSB"   "MScB"  
# [12] "MaScB"  "MSBa"   "MaSBa"  "MScBa"  "MaScBa" "BMS"    "BaMS"   "BMaS"   "BaMaS"  "BMSc"   "BaMSc" 
# [23] "BMaSc"  "BaMaSc" "BSM"    "BaSM"   "BScM"   "BaScM"  "BSMa"   "BaSMa"  "BScMa"  "BaScMa" "SMB"   
# [34] "ScMB"   "SMaB"   "ScMaB"  "SMBa"   "ScMBa"  "SMaBa"  "ScMaBa" "SBM"    "ScBM"   "SBaM"   "ScBaM" 
# [45] "SBMa"   "ScBMa"  "SBaMa"  "ScBaMa"
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe we can try the code below

```
d <- do.call(
  rbind,
  combn(
    c(first_letter, second_letter),
    3,
    pracma::perms,
    simplify = FALSE
  )
)

res <- do.call(
  paste0,
  data.frame(d)
)[apply(
  `dim<-`(match(substr(d, 1, 1), first_letter), dim(d)),
  1, 
  function(x) all(!duplicated(x))
)]
```

which gives

```
> res
 [1] "SBM"    "SMB"    "BSM"    "BMS"    "MBS"    "MSB"    "ScBM"   "ScMB"  
 [9] "BScM"   "BMSc"   "MBSc"   "MScB"   "BaSM"   "BaMS"   "SBaM"   "SMBa"
[17] "MSBa"   "MBaS"   "ScBaM"  "ScMBa"  "BaScM"  "BaMSc"  "MBaSc"  "MScBa"
[25] "MaSB"   "MaBS"   "SMaB"   "SBMa"   "BSMa"   "BMaS"   "ScMaB"  "ScBMa"
[33] "MaScB"  "MaBSc"  "BMaSc"  "BScMa"  "BaMaS"  "BaSMa"  "MaBaS"  "MaSBa"
[41] "SMaBa"  "SBaMa"  "ScBaMa" "ScMaBa" "BaScMa" "BaMaSc" "MaBaSc" "MaScBa"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `permutations` from package `e1071` (Misc Functions of the Department of Statistics, Probability
Theory Group (Formerly: E1071)).

```
library(e1071)

res <- c(substr(inputs,1,1), substr(inputs,1,2))
res
[1] "M"  "B"  "S"  "Ma" "Ba" "Sc"

perm <- unique(matrix(e1071::permutations(6), ncol=3))

# to exclude repetitions find 1,4 2,5 and 3,6
apply(matrix(res[perm], ncol=3), 1, paste, collapse="")[
  rowSums(cbind(rowSums(perm == 1 | perm == 4)==2,
                rowSums(perm == 2 | perm == 5)==2,
                rowSums(perm == 3 | perm == 6)==2))==0]
 [1] "MSBa"   "SMBa"   "SMaBa"  "MaSBa"  "SMaB"   "BMaS"   "SMB"    "SBM"   
 [9] "MBS"    "BMS"    "BSM"    "MSB"    "MaBS"   "MaSB"   "BSMa"   "SBMa"  
[17] "SBaM"   "MBaS"   "MaBaS"  "SBaMa"  "BaSMa"  "BaSM"   "BaMS"   "BaMaS" 
[25] "BMaSc"  "MBSc"   "BMSc"   "MaBSc"  "MBaSc"  "MaBaSc" "BaMSc"  "BaMaSc"
[33] "MaScB"  "BScM"   "MScB"   "BScMa"  "BaScM"  "BaScMa" "MScBa"  "MaScBa"
[41] "ScBMa"  "ScMB"   "ScBM"   "ScMaB"  "ScMBa"  "ScMaBa" "ScBaM"  "ScBaMa"
```

Alternatively you can also construct the permutations with **base R**

```
res <- c(substr(inputs,1,1), substr(inputs,1,2))
res
[1] "M"  "B"  "S"  "Ma" "Ba" "Sc"

perm <- as.matrix(expand.grid(1:6,1:6,1:6))

perm <- perm[colSums(apply(perm, 1, duplicated))==0,]

# to exclude repetitions find 1,4 2,5 and 3,6
apply(matrix(res[perm], ncol=3), 1, paste, collapse="")[
  rowSums(cbind(rowSums(perm == 1 | perm == 4)==2,
                rowSums(perm == 2 | perm == 5)==2,
                rowSums(perm == 3 | perm == 6)==2))==0]
 [1] "SBM"    "ScBM"   "BSM"    "BaSM"   "SBaM"   "ScBaM"  "BScM"   "BaScM" 
 [9] "SMB"    "ScMB"   "MSB"    "MaSB"   "SMaB"   "ScMaB"  "MScB"   "MaScB" 
[17] "BMS"    "BaMS"   "MBS"    "MaBS"   "BMaS"   "BaMaS"  "MBaS"   "MaBaS" 
[25] "SBMa"   "ScBMa"  "BSMa"   "BaSMa"  "SBaMa"  "ScBaMa" "BScMa"  "BaScMa"
[33] "SMBa"   "ScMBa"  "MSBa"   "MaSBa"  "SMaBa"  "ScMaBa" "MScBa"  "MaScBa"
[41] "BMSc"   "BaMSc"  "MBSc"   "MaBSc"  "BMaSc"  "BaMaSc" "MBaSc"  "MaBaSc"
```